# Spring context cache between integration tests - slow startup times

Tags: spring, startup

I have a spring boot application and when I am doing some integration testing I must wait the spring context to load, for example it takes about 4 seconds for the JPA slice (I know this is not too much time). Is there a way to make this instant at least while I am developing?

e.g. something like spring-dev-tools but between integration test runs, or run a separate integration testing application, or lazy init whole spring boot context

Comment: Unfortunately integration tests require the spring context to be up and running. You could create one or more Application classes specifically for integration tests where you can exclude some classes from the component scan, so you can make tests with smaller scopes which are faster contingent you remember to load every dependency that needs injection. 

    i'd rely more on unit tests which are very fast and more independent and provide you with fast feedback then on integration tests.

Comment: Thanks @Raphael, but I was thinking a more universal, plug and play and faster solution for development time. Integration tests are minimized of course, but when I need them e.g. developing/testing a complex sql query against different scenarios, I find the 5sec feedback loop disturbing